# Hiding and displaying content with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the content on a page depending on which link is clicked. My problem is that once the content for a link is displayed it wont disappear if another link is clicked even if I have set it to display none when the other link is clicked. The display: block is overwriting the display: none.

For those of you suggesting I use .show() and .hide() I appreciate your help but I don't think this method will be best for me as I need to add a class to the elements so I can animate it later. Thanks

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#link_one').click(function() {
    jQuery('#about_us').addClass('hide');
    jQuery('#why_us').addClass('hide');
    jQuery('#our_prods').addClass('hide');
    jQuery('#accreditations').addClass('show');
  });

  jQuery('#link_two').click(function() {
    jQuery('#why_us').addClass('hide');
    jQuery('#accreditations').addClass('hide');
    jQuery('#our_prods').addClass('hide');
    jQuery('#about_us').addClass('show');
  });

  jQuery('#link_three').click(function() {
    jQuery('#about_us').addClass('hide');
    jQuery('#our_prods').addClass('hide');
    jQuery('#accreditations').addClass('hide');
    jQuery('#why_us').addClass('show');
  });

});
```

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

p {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a id="link_one" href="#">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a id="link_two" href="#">link 2</a></li>
    <li><a id="link_three" href="#">link 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="about_us">
  <p>About Us Page - to be displayed by default</p>
</div>

<div id="accreditations">
  <p>Accreditations Page Content - Link 1</p>
</div>

<div id="our_prods">
  <p>Our products - Link 2</p>
</div>

<div id="why_us">
  <p>Why us content - link 3</p>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/Reece_Dev/pen/gWdEoJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what I'd do and recommend doing:

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="link_1" class="link" data-target="accreditations">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="link_2" class="link" data-target="our_prods">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="link_3" class="link" data-target="why_us">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="pageContainer" id="uniqueID">
    <!-- content -->
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.link').on('click', function()
    {
        $('.pageContainer').addClass('hide');
        $('#'+ $(this).data('target')).removeClass('hide');
    });
});
```

what this will do is, when anything with class `.link` is clicked, add a class ('hide') to all elements that have the class `.pageContainer`. Then it will remove the class from the div with the id that matches the target (a console.log of the `$('#'+ $(this).data('target'))` should result in `$('#why_us')` - if the why_us link was clicked

data is an attribute you can attach to elements, data-* - * can be anything you want, but makes more sense to call it something related. calling .data() will get an array of all available data tags on the element, doing .data('string') will get the data element that matches data-string.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/data-*

Comment: Could you please explain what data-target="" does? Thanks

Comment: sure - was genuinely meant to ahha

Comment: @Reece no worries glad it helped :)

Comment: Got another question I know that $(this) stands for the current selected object. But what does '#' select. Sorry for all the questions I did try look it up haha

Comment: @Reece `$(this)` refers to the current object and `#` refers to ids and `.` refers to a class. so doing `#id` with find the div with the id of id :)

Comment: Yeah I just realised as you messaged haha. But thanks I appreciate all your help

Comment: @Reece no worries :)

Answer (score 2):

With your actual code you are not toggling the `hide` and `show` classes correctly.

You can just use jQuery `.hide()` and `.show()` methods, instead of adding and removing classes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#link_one').click(function() {
    $('#about_us').hide();
    $('#why_us').hide();
    $('#our_prods').hide();
    $('#accreditations').show();
  });
  $('#link_two').click(function() {
    $('#why_us').hide();
    $('#accreditations').hide();
    $('#our_prods').hide();
    $('#about_us').show();
  });
  $('#link_three').click(function() {
    $('#about_us').hide();
    $('#our_prods').hide();
    $('#accreditations').hide();
    $('#why_us').show();
  });

});
```

**Demo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#link_one').click(function() {
    $('#about_us').hide();
    $('#why_us').hide();
    $('#our_prods').hide();
    $('#accreditations').show();
  });

  $('#link_two').click(function() {
    $('#why_us').hide();
    $('#accreditations').hide();
    $('#our_prods').hide();
    $('#about_us').show();
  });

  $('#link_three').click(function() {
    $('#about_us').hide();
    $('#our_prods').hide();
    $('#accreditations').hide();
    $('#why_us').show();
  });

});
```

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

p {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a id="link_one" href="#">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a id="link_two" href="#">link 2</a></li>
    <li><a id="link_three" href="#">link 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="about_us">
  <p>About Us Page - to be displayed by default</p>
</div>

<div id="accreditations">
  <p>Accreditations Page Content - Link 1</p>
</div>

<div id="our_prods">
  <p>Our products - Link 2</p>
</div>

<div id="why_us">
  <p>Why us content - link 3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use jquery show hide function instead of addClass. as when you add hide class to already added show element, display block will override display none. instead use this.

```
jQuery('#link_one').click(function() {
    jQuery('#about_us').hide();
    jQuery('#why_us').hide();
    jQuery('#our_prods').hide();
    jQuery('#accreditations').show();
});

jQuery('#link_two').click(function() {
    jQuery('#why_us').hide();
    jQuery('#accreditations').hide();
    jQuery('#our_prods').hide();
    jQuery('#about_us').show();
});

jQuery('#link_three').click(function() {
    jQuery('#about_us').hide();
    jQuery('#our_prods').hide();
    jQuery('#accreditations').hide();
    jQuery('#why_us').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're never removing the class, so once you click a link it has both the `hide` and `show` classes. And because the `show` class is later in your css, it overrides the `hide` class.

You can add `.removeClass('show')` at the end of your changes. Like

```
jQuery('#our_prods').addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
```

An easier method might be to use the `show()` and `hide()` jQuery methods, and not worry about swapping the classes.

```
jQuery('#link_two').click(function() {
  jQuery('#why_us').hide();
  jQuery('#accreditations').hide();
  jQuery('#our_prods').hide();
  jQuery('#about_us').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're now removing the class show when you're trying to hide the content.

Also, the better way to that is by using the jquery hide and show functions.

The script changes to this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery('#link_one').click(function() {
        jQuery('.content').hide()
        jQuery('#accreditations').show()
      });

      jQuery('#link_two').click(function() {
            jQuery('.content').hide()
        jQuery('#our_prods').show()
      });

      jQuery('#link_three').click(function() {
            jQuery('.content').hide()
        jQuery('#why_us').show()
      });

});
</script>
```

And we added a class content to the page containers.

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a id="link_one" href="#">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a id="link_two" href="#">link 2</a></li>
    <li><a id="link_three" href="#">link 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="about_us" class="content show">
  <p>About Us Page - to be displayed by default</p>
</div>

<div id="accreditations" class="content">
  <p>Accreditations Page Content - Link 1</p>
</div>

<div id="our_prods" class="content">
  <p>Our products - Link 2</p>
</div>

<div id="why_us" class="content">
  <p>Why us content - link 3</p>
</div>
```

The updated Css :

```
<style type="text/css">

    nav {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

p {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.content{
    display: none;
}
.show{
    display: block;
}
</style>
```